# Apple Push Notifications registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: method

Tags: ios, push-notification

When iOS device registers for remote notifications, it registers with the Apple Service by calling the method:

```
 registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
```

Is that method synchronous or asynchronous?

What happens if the device for some reason cannot obtain token immediatley? Does it call `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError` or it just keeps waiting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According developer.apple.com, registerForRemoteNotificationTypes is asynchronous:

When you send this message, the device initiates the registration process with Apple Push Service. If it succeeds, the application delegate receives a device token in the application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: method; if registration doesn’t succeed or failed to receive token, the delegate is informed via the application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: method.